# Cypress - click, move, release mouse action

Tags: cypress

I would like to emulate mouse function (click , hold (move) and release) via Cypress to create timeslot (click on the mouse and select several hours blocks) [Timeslot_web_element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COe0Z.jpg)

I have tried triggers to move with mouse (mousedown, mouse up...).

I have tried:

```
cy.get(':nth-child(36) > .fc-timegrid-slot-lane')
.trigger('mousedown', { which: 1, pageX: 684.625, pageY: 704.188 })
.trigger('mousemove', { which: 1, pageX: 762.875, pageY: 782.438 })
.trigger('mouseup')
```

No success.

[Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qik38.jpg)

I use Cypress 12.7

Any idea, please ?

Thanks

Comment: The syntax looks correct but that's all that can be said. Do you have the right selector? Do you have the events? What are you moving to where? Are there any frameworks or libraries involved? Please provide sufficient details to answer the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drag & Drop - create a new timeslot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75628620/drag-drop-create-a-new-timeslot)

Comment: I am sorry. Something happend during posting and the screenshots were removed. The post is updated with link of pictures.

My target is to create timselot for actual day from 11am to 1pm. So I have to click on element of calendar and move down to selecet several blocks of calendar and then release my action.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use {force: true}. I saw in the error your element is covered by another element.

```
cy.get(':nth-child(36) > .fc-timegrid-slot-lane')
.trigger('mousedown', { which: 1, pageX: 684.625, pageY: 704.188 }, {force: true})
.trigger('mousemove', { which: 1, pageX: 762.875, pageY: 782.438 }, {force: true})
.trigger('mouseup')
```

Comment: I already did it, but has not helped me. As you can see (the first screenshot), there is not element span with attribute LEFT. it looks like it appears during test... what's more creepy, If I do it manually, I cannot catch this attribute.

Comment: I see. It's weird.. I wonder what's the error says after you added the force: true then..

or you can add a bit of wait time before mousemove maybe half a second .wait(500)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it has not helped me. I also tried longer wait or other similar suggestions that was found via google. No success. It looks like that this is very weird situation. Btw. thanks for help.